# Career Advice to move away from QA

Tags: career-development, career-switch, careers, mentoring

I need a career advice very badly.

**About Myself:**

I have software test automation (QA) experience for more than 10 years. I am also in a good job with decent salary. However I have been trying to leave this QA and move to development as QA is mostly considered as second class citizens. This is where I need some inputs from you guys.

I have done Bachelor of Engineering. I am in US with a VISA sponsorship.

I am good in core java, design patterns, nodeJS. I do NOT like to be a people manager. would like to stay in technical as much as possible. Would prefer an architect path.

**What excites me:**

I love coding - As part of automation i write code. however it does not go to production :) ..as you know testing is basically a value adding job.

**Some Options:**

I am confused how to go next. These are options i was thinking about.

- I was trying to learn ethereum/solidity/reactJS. It was fun and was able to develop a decent DAPP. But I do not think I could get a job in ethereum/solidity in a decent sized company as it is in early stage. Only start ups are doing this mostly. (I can not move to startups as they might not do VISA stuffs)
- As I am decent in Java, I thought I could learn Spring boot & move into Java development.
- I also like machine learning. I have a lot to learn. But mostly industry seems to prefer people with PhD. Doing masters and Phd is not an option now for me.

Please feel free to suggest anything you like (But No QA / test automation / performance testing - anything part of QA)

Comment: There are organizations where QA people are not second class citizens.

Comment: What do you enjoy doing?

Comment: @BenMz, I love coding. even as part of automation i do write code. however test scripts do not go to production. There are very few org where QA might be treated better as you had said. But being in some sort of development will give me more options.

Comment: I'd was going to write you an answer when I had time time but now I can't. Sorry.

Comment: @BenMz i would appreciate any input. Thanks for helping

Comment: At some level above you, there is a development manager in a position parallel you a QA manager. Talk to that manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the biggest problem with staying in QA or support roles - keep it up for longer than 6 months or a year and that is all some HR folks will see you as capable of doing. You need to work hard to change this perception of your skillset.

Create a GitHub account and start creating a public portfolio of work which you can show off. The portfolio can be anything - small utilities to perform basic functions like an alarm clock or browser plugins to monitor usage for instance, then you can move on to more complex projects. Create your own website to show off your skills and add links to both in your CV. Get involved in open source projects.

Over the last decade you must have worked with a number of people who have since moved on to other companies. Use this network of former colleagues to help try to get through the HR screen as much as possible.

Learn the buzzwords - these are the only things the vast majority of HR drones know about technology. Be able to explain the principles of object oriented programming. Learn about frontend frameworks like angular and design patterns like the factory pattern.

Be able to tell some stories about what happens when best practice isn't followed: "So the data centre suffered a power cut and the generator failed to start as birds had nested in the air intake of the diesel generator. This meant it couldn't get enough O2 to run so the UPS batteries ran out and the DB servers all shut down. Took 18 hours for all the integrity checks to finish and the entire company was sitting on its hands! All because nobody has tested the diesel generator in the last 5 years".

Comment: People who work in HR are not drones.

Comment: @user1666620, Yes those are good ways to showcase skills. but my concern was choosing the path. there are multiple technologies. thats where i am confused

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I agree. I am looking for some inputs from people with market trend and stuff. I am trying to avoid any further mistake

Comment: @KitKarson If there's one thing I've learned about "market trends" in software dev, it's that they change faster than you can keep up with, more often than not.  Whatever's hot today won't be so hot next year, and whatever's going to be hot next year probably hasn't even been invented yet.  No matter what you choose for now, you *will* need to learn new technologies as you go forward, so pick the thing you feel most comfortable with and run with it.  The only mistake is allowing yourself to become frozen by indecision.

Comment: @Steve-O, True. Thanks for your input. I really appreciate it.